Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't see /etc/resolv.conf
Content of /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
some-domain 127.0.0.1
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

However the ip is another:
dig some-domain                                          3.65s  11:17:37 

; <<>> DiG 9.18.28-0ubuntu0.22.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> some-domain
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 27200
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;some-domain.           IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Sun Aug 25 11:17:42 EDT 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 40

127.0.0.53 instead of 127.0.0.1 as it in /etc/resolv.conf

/etc/resolv.conf is managed (generated) by systemd-dnsmasq. Read man systemd-dnsmasq. Also, in networking, the IP addresses 127.*.*.* all refer to localhost.

If you’re trying to specify an IP address for a domain, then this should be added to your /etc/hosts file.

When you write some-domain 127.0.0.1 you are using an undefined command.  It is ignored.
Thus, when you write dig some-domain, this is translated as a lookup of some-domain. (according to your search command), and requested of 127.0.0.53 (according to your nameserver command).  We don't see AD in the reply, presumably because the request failed, but we do see EDNS (according to your options command).
So it did see resolv.conf, and did what it said.
